# SQL Server recursive common table expression how to get only matching manager record

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I am new to CTE in SQL Server. I am trying with the example from https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1520/recursive-queries-using-common-table-expressions-cte-in-sql-server/

I wan to get only the employees reporting to a manager who are having a record in another table i.e `UserTag` table eg: In the following table, UserId: 100 is what my test user, he has got following manager hierarchy. Someone in his manager hierarchy, got a record in UserTag. i want that manager id.

This should happen for all users in 'User' table.

```
User
====
UserId  ManagerId
100     101
101     102
102     103
103     104

UserTag
========
Id  UserId  TagId   TagName
1   103     1       'test'

Expected Result:
UserId  ManagerWithTagId
100     103

WITH Managers AS 
( 
    -- initialization 
    SELECT Id, Email, ManagerID
    FROM dbo.[User] 

    UNION ALL 

    -- recursive execution 
    SELECT u.Id, u.Email, u.ManagerID
    FROM dbo.[User] u 
    INNER JOIN Managers m ON m.ManagerID = u.ID
    --INNER JOIN UserTag UT ON UT.UserId = u.ID
    WHERE UT.TagName = 'test'
) 
SELECT * 
FROM Managers
```

With the above query i.e commented the UserTag table. i am getting the complete manager hierarchy of particular user. But not sure how to proceed to get my expected result?

Can anyone help me how to achieve this?

Comment: Please show the table structure (by providing the SQL DDL), and provide some sample data and expected results from your query

Comment: Are you *sure* you need a rCTE? *"I wan to get only the employees reporting to a manager who are having a record in another table"* Suggests you want an `EXISTS`. Please, however, see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/2029983); what specifically is it you need help with? **Consumable** sampled and expected results will help us help you.

Comment: What does that give you and what do you expect to see?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this, I may have hacked the later bit as did find that a bit hard to get. I can get the hierarchy, imagine there are better people who know a nice way for the last bit.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Usr (
    UserId INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_Usr PRIMARY KEY,
    ManagerId INT NULL
);

INSERT INTO dbo.Usr (UserId, ManagerId)
VALUES 
(100, 101),
(101, 102), 
(102, 103), 
(103, 104),
(104, NULL);

CREATE TABLE dbo.UsrTag (
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) CONSTRAINT PK_UsrTag PRIMARY KEY, 
    UserId INT NOT NULL, 
    TagId INT NOT NULL, 
    TagName NVARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO dbo.UsrTag (UserId, TagId, TagName)
VALUES
(103, 1, 'test'),
(102, 3, 'test2');


---------------------------------------
GO

DECLARE @UserId INT = 100;

WITH Managers AS (
    SELECT UserId, ManagerId, 1 AS [Level]
    FROM dbo.Usr
    WHERE UserId = @UserId

    UNION ALL

    SELECT U.UserId, U.ManagerId, M.[Level] + 1
    FROM Managers AS M
    INNER JOIN dbo.Usr AS U ON U.UserId = M.ManagerId
)

-- SELECT * FROM Managers

-- Try and now use the data and filter out any user tags not matching the required value
SELECT TOP 1 
M.UserId, 
UT.UserId AS TopLevelManagerUserId
FROM Managers AS M
LEFT JOIN dbo.UsrTag AS UT ON UT.TagName = 'test'
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 M1.UserId 
    FROM Managers AS M1
    LEFT JOIN dbo.UsrTag AS UT1 ON UT1.TagName = 'test'
    ORDER BY [Level] DESC
) AS T
ORDER BY M.[Level]
```

It was based on this one [Recursively get last record from same table parent child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55353807/recursively-get-last-record-from-same-table-parent-child)